# Is there a list of the Korean Syllable characters mapped to Unicode?

Tags: transliteration

I see a [table of all the Hangul Syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables). Is there a machine readable format mapping the Hangul unicode values to their romanization / transliteration counterpart? There are so many syllables to do it manually.

Comment: Depending on what you need it for, it's more complicated than it seems.  E.g., characters 밀 and 양 will be transliterated to _mil_ and _yang_, respectively, but due to the way Korean sounds work, 밀양 is transliterated into _miryang_.  There are even a few cases where you can't reasonably do it algorithmically, like Seoul's 학여울 (Hangnyeoul) station.

Comment: Potentially useful resource: http://roman.cs.pusan.ac.kr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I made one finally.

```
가,ㄱㅏ
각,ㄱㅏㄱ
갂,ㄱㅏㄲ
갃,ㄱㅏㄳ
간,ㄱㅏㄴ
갅,ㄱㅏㄵ
```

... Full thing [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/ba561dffb8611ddb222784b3d01a497f).

Answer (score 0):

Combining [Jamo unicodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Jamo_(Unicode_block)) with well-established romanization rules (such as [Yale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_romanization_of_Korean) which is de facto standard in linguistics community), you might be able to come up with automatic romanization / de-romanization with some implementational tricks (e.g. syllable boundaries).